# How to write activemodel serializer for many to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, active-model-serializers

Trying to set up the backend for an ember-cli app. Here's how the models look like in Ember:

**post.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  heading: DS.attr('string'),
  content: DS.attr(''),
  imageUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  pageId: DS.belongsTo('page'),
  tagIds: DS.hasMany('tag')
});
```

**tag.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  postIds: DS.hasMany('post')
});
```

The models in Rails and Active Record are just Post, Tag, and Theme. Theme joins Post and Tag. (ie: Post has_many :tags, through: :themes)

Here's what my serializers look like:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  attributes :id, :heading, :content, :image_url

  has_many :tags
end

class TagSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  attributes :id, :name
end
```

This works in one direction: searching posts will get all the tags as well. Doesn't work in the other because I don't have a has_many in the TagSerializer. However, if I put a has_many in both serializers, there will be a stack level too deep error.

So I guess my question is: What is the typical way to implement a many-to-many relationship with ActiveModel serializer? I can't seem to find any resources on how to set this up in a Rails back end. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a "stack level too deep" error because each serializer is recursively embedding the other.

I'd start by making sure you're using `includes` in your Rails controller:

```
# posts controller
def show
  post = Post.includes(:tags).find_by id: params[:id]
  render json: post
end

# tags controller
def show
  tag = Tag.includes(:posts).find_by id: params[:id]
  render json: post
end
```

Then, in your serializer, tell it to conditionally include tags / posts only if the association has been loaded:

```
# post serializer
def include_tags?
  object.association(:tags).loaded?
end

# tag serializer
def include_posts?
  object.association(:posts).loaded?
end
```

After this, it should only cascade down one level.

As a side note, you'll probably want to rename the `tagIds` and `postIds` properties in your ember models to `tags` and `posts`.

Comment: Thanks! tagIds and postIds seem to be the default using the ActiveModel adapter

Comment: Hey Chris, could you explain further the second snippet of code? I'm not sure how to use the include_tags? and include_posts? part.

Comment: Sure. ActiveModelSerializers automatically calls `include_<thing>?` (if it's defined) to determine if the json for an attribute or association should be in the final output. It's also useful to conditionally show attributes if the current user is the owner or admin for example.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this and looked up a post by id. The XHR response gave me one post with tags as an empty array. Looks OK.